# Which one is correct? the last or last

Tags: grammar

What is correct “the last” or “last”?

I haven’t read any book since “the last Saturday”/“last Saturday”.

I read an article that we use last before a specific past time reference such as Monday. So day in a week are never preceded by THE LAST but just by LAST apart from if it is a specific reference in time e.g. It was on TV the last Monday in November.?

Thank you

Comment: “Last Saturday”, not “the last”.... “*You use last in expressions such as last Friday, last night, and last year to refer, for example,to the most recent Friday, night, or year. ——- 
I got married last July.
He never made it home at all last night.
It is not surprising they did so badly in last year's elections.*” https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/last

Answer (score 2):

"last Saturday" means the previous Saturday, the one before we are talking.

"the last Saturday" means the final Saturday in a period of time.

So "The last Saturday in November" is perfectly correct. So is "I haven't read a book since last Saturday"; but also "I haven't read a book since the last Saturday of November".

"the last Saturday" without a qualification would mean the final Saturday of all time, for example if the Earth was being destroyed in less than a week.

Comment: It could also mean the last Saturday of some agreed-upon period of time, although "that last Saturday" would get the idea over better.

Comment: Right, for example: "My last semester in college I studied every weekend, but the last Saturday I went to the bar with my friends.". Here the context sets the period of time, and "last Saturday" is the last one in the contextually defined period.